# An iframe is wider than it should on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, iframe, responsive-design

I have an iframe that I am embedding into a responsive WordPress theme. It looks good on some mobile devices, but on iPhone, the iframe is a bit wider than it should and it gets out of the container so users can't see the right part of the iframe (which is probably around 20-30px). This happens on portrait mode - if the orientation is set on landscape, it looks ok.

The content of the iframe is responsive as well, I'm using bootstrap. Also it looks ok on resized desktop browsers and on Android mobile devices. So the problem is only with the portrait iPhone orientation.

I am using this in the head of my iframe:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it do the same thing on a browser that is resized to match the iPhone's portrait width? Maybe some element/style is hitting a minimum size that is bigger than the iPhone's width?

Comment: No, it looks good on any other browser whether it is a resized desktop browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) or an Android browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that mobile Safari ignores the iframe `width` attribute. I created a new question here and answered it myself with the solution: [How to set the width of an iframe in iOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865899/how-to-set-the-width-of-an-iframe-in-ios6)

Answer (score 10):

Mobile Safari seems to not recognize width attributes on iframe, but recognizes min-width.

```
iframe{
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Need to look into this further, but this did the trick for me. Thought I was going mad - so thanks!

Comment: I also had to add scrolling="no" to make it works. However, it has to be conditional since with this change, it causes the iframe on other devices to not work properly.

Comment: iframe{
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
and plus scrolling="no" in iframe attribute works for me
(ios 11, cordova - webview)

Answer (score 2):

For the meta tag try starting with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If that doesn't solve it, look for what's causing the frame to be too wide, e.g. iframe dimension settings, width, padding or margins of elements inside the iframe, as well as margins or padding on the WordPress div that contains the iframe.

Remember that the iframe content is a completely seperate document so you need to double check details in both the parent WordPress page and the iframe page.

Good luck!

**edit**
You could also check it's not a default browser setting by using a reset in your WordPress CSS, e.g.

```
iframe{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did try that meta line but with no luck. Also I don't think there is anything wrong inside the iframe since any other browser correctly displays it.

Comment: Do you have a URL to demonstrate the issue @watt?

Comment: What about margin or padding on the element that contains the iframe? For example, the parent WordPress page may have a 10 - 20px left and right margin or padding.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a URL yet. Also there is no margin/padding set. Tried with a blank html template and I get the same issue, so it's not related to the theme.

Comment: I think it's somehow related to the width attribute of the iframe. The iframe looks like it doesn't take it into account on Iphones...