# How to set the width of an iframe in iOS6?

Tags: iframe, ios6, safari

I have an iframe that must be embedded on some websites and it is not well displayed on iPhones. This is because the `width` attribute (probably `height` as well) is ignored by mobile Safari.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` parameter of the iframe is ignored in mobile Safari so the width must be set in px with CSS.

I fixed the problem by checking the user agent with JavaScript. If it's an iOS device, I set the width of the iframe in px with CSS to be the exact size as the container.

Answer (score 6):

Although `width` is ignored, `min-width` isn't. So something like this has the same effect as `width:100%`:

```
iframe {
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```